# Need "How To" to Rebuild OpenCV v2.4.12 and v.3.1 for Android and NDK 11

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio, android-ndk

I trying to rebuild OpenCV static libraries for the Android ABIs of: armeabi, armeabi-7a, mips, x86.

I'm using Android Studio (because Eclipse is deprecated) latest and greatest version on Mac OS X.

I using NDK 11 that recommends Clang3.8, GCC is deprecated. Use the APP_STL (Application.mk) of libc++ instead of libstdc++.

Threading Building Blocks (libtbb.a) support: clearly indicate or configure in CMake generator for Android on Mac OS X whether tbb is supported for one more of the Android ABIs.

My current problem is the following link error building a shared library for an Android APK where a static library created by the OpenCV Android armeabi-7a CMake build does not link with libtbb.a, that was created by the same build process:

.../libopencv_imgproc.a(histogram.cpp.o):

histogram.cpp:

function tbb::interface7::internal::auto_partition_type::auto_partition_type(tbb::auto_partitioner const&):

error: undefined reference to 'tbb::internal::get_initial_auto_partitioner_divisor()'

[Many more errors like this one...]

Here is my cmake command:
cmake \
-DBUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
-DBUILD_TESTS=OFF  \
-DBUILD_WITH_DEBUG_INFO=OFF \
-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF \
-DWITH_TBB=ON \
-DENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS=OFF \
-DCMAKE_BUILD_WITH_INSTALL_RPATH=ON \
-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE="-Os -DNDEBUG -fvisibility=hidden -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-all" \
-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE="-Os -DNDEBUG -fvisibility=hidden -ffunction-sections -fstack-protector-all -fvisibility-inlines-hidden" \
-DANDROID_ABI=armeabi-v7a \
-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN_NAME=arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 \
-DANDROID_STL=c++_static \
-DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=android-15 \
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=../android/android.toolchain.cmake \
../..

Comment: Definitely looks like TBB isn't linked in. Are you sure that libtbb.a was built? Can you see the built library in your build area? Also, do you want shared libraries or static archives? You say shared in your question, but then you use BUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF.

Comment: Yes, I'm absolutely sure the libtbb.a is being built by the OpenCV CMake make process. Regarding "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF," - Not sure where you seeing "shared" but I want to build the OpenCV dependencies as "static" libraries and then, using  ndk-build, build an Android shared library that links against the OpenCV static libraries I built. The nkd-build is where I get the link errors.

Answer (score 0):

The link error resulted from me fat fingering a change of an assign operator, ":=", to a plus-equal operator, "+=", in the OpenCV produced OpenCV.mk file for Android cross-compilation. But the overall problem with CMake generated build environments remain. That is the initial CMake configuration definition settings are only known to the CMake project author. This requires the CMake project author to correctly and clearly document the CMake definitions that will build the specific target, whether it is a cross-compiling build environment or a platform specific build environment. Without proper documentation, it's is very hard to reverse engineer the CMake script/package, whatever you call it, to figure how platform specific build configuration settings map to CMake configuration definitions.